Microwave oven install
I got a replacement microwave and the guy that installed it did not do that paper instructions alignment from below the cabinet before drilling the nails above the cabinet. I think he just drilled a random hole and I feel he created a new metal hole on the microwave. Is that a problem?

Making a new hole in an appliance that isn't designed to have a hole is a problem, but your information isn't clear on whether that's the case. Please [edit] your question to include additional details that could lead to an answer. As it stands we would have to guess, and we're not even in the same room as your microwave...

if he drilled into the microwave oven, then he owes you a new oven

Anything that we can't see could always be a problem.   We don't know how far he drilled into the microwave.
Microwave mounting brackets or bars come in a decent amount of variety.   Sometimes there is a sheet that attaches to the top of microwave then you drilling into that from below.   Sometimes it is two bars and sometimes they have L brackets (less common for ones I have done).  He could have gotten your old one to fit on the new microwave (can be done if old one used universal or bars).
If it had a metal sheet below it is possible that the guy used preexisting holes and went into the sheet.    If he used screws (pointy tip) instead of bolts it is highly likely he did this.    You can also do this with the bars.   You don't HAVE to use their guides (but it is easier) you can just measure the distance from the front and go in there (but if you hit midhole you have to punch another one).
Also don't discount that this guy has done a million of these and just quickly measured where the holes were and popped it.   I have a guy that does this with everything he installs - some screwing savant.   As far a dangerous we don't know for sure but if the screw isn't popping through the main part of microwave probably not an issue.   And going through the actual cover of most mid range oven models would be very difficult and he would have had a lot of torque being used.
Here is the deal.   Is your microwave straight and in the right place?   Can you wiggle it or move it?    You should not be able to wiggle it at all.   That would indicate that he didn't put enough screws in or they aren't tightened.

I generally agree, but I'm not sure a wiggle is a good test. Added load and vibration could result in a screw merely in the cabinet failing. Every one I've installed (of many) has had the screws going into a heavy threaded receptacle. IMO this install is completely unacceptable, if only for the lack of knowing.

The install is not unacceptable because we do not know about HOW it was done. The only info we have is from a concerned homeowner that has suspicions and doesn't know the difference between  screws and nails.

@RMDman - that is my thoughts.   The guys I have that are really really fast at this stuff - the guys that make me pay by project not hour - look like they are half assing everything because they are so fast.    However they do everything right to a T.    So I asked her to wiggle it.    If the microwave isn't in the mounting bracket it will wiggle if you just screwed it to the bar or a bracket (I guess there is a chance it couldn't but an adult should be able to wiggle it).
